# Fetch all data from from JSON and display in HTML via method's Class

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, fetch-api, es6-class

I'm working with fetch api & json. After fetch data from data.json, loop forEach display only last object turning into hmtl element using Class method, where writing console.log return all of object from array.

```
class UI {
    displayData(name) {
        const list = document.getElementById('data');
        list.innerHTML = `<p>${name}</p>`;
    }
}

fetch ('./data/data.json')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
        json.forEach(element => {
            const ui = new UI;
            ui.displayData(element)
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Add "+" before equal "=" in list.innerHTML in UI Class to add next html element to const "list".

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in your self-answer, there wasn't any concatenation happening so you were overwriting your data.

I'm writing this answer to propose a bit of a refactored version of what you're doing.  If you simply concatenate arbitrary data into the context of HTML (which you're doing with your template string), you risk creating invalid HTML or even ending up with security issues.  You must escape the data for use.  The easiest/best way to do this is not to set the `innerHTML` at all, but the `innerText`.  Perhaps try something like this... untested but should get you started.

```
class UI() {
  getListItem(item) {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = item;
    return p;
  }

  render(data) {
    const list = document.getElementById('data');
    data.map(this.getListItem).forEach((listItemP) => {
      list.appendChild(listItemP);
    });
  }
}

const ui = new UI();
fetch ('./data/data.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(ui.render);
```